# Read file directories from text file and copy them to a remote server using Msbuilds

Tags: msbuild, copy, unzip, 7zip, msbuild-task

I have a textfile `FileList.txt` which has the following content

```
D:\Temp\File1.zip
D:\Temp\File2.zip
```

I want these files to be moved over to another server and unzipped during the build execution .

The basic operations that need to be done are

```
    1. Read the text file
    2. Copy the files one by one to another server
    3. Unzip the files copied
```

I am using the following code

```
<ReadLinesFromFile File='$(UpgradeSequenceFilePath)' > <Output TaskParameter="Lines"  ItemName="DirectoryList" />  </ReadLinesFromFile>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(DirectoryList)" DestinationFolder="$(DatabaseInstallerRemotePath)" />
```

This copies the files for me. How do I unzip the files now?

Comment: What have you tried, i.e. do you have an actual code problem? Any of those points are easy to find by search for 'how to do x with msbuild': it's just a matter of ReadLinesFromFile/Copy/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Unzip

Comment: DestinationFolder has to be one single directory. I assume DestinationFolder="$(DatabaseInstallerRemotePath)" is what you're after?

Comment: Yes, I made that change and it worked for me. Anything on the unzipping?

Comment: As said, download MSBuild Community Tasks, import it and use Unzip